# How do I get my Javascript to work with all views in Javascript/Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

Handlebars has a feature where I can load a bunch of subdocuments. Inside the main document.

[image: project]

Inside *main.handlebars* I have my menu items that when clicked will load *home.handlebars*, *license.handlebars*, etc. A page reload does happen.

*main.handlebars* loads my *index.js* file.

But that JS file will return an error because an element it's trying to access via

`const dataFromDB = document.querySelector('.elementFromHome')`

is inside *home.handlebars*

[image: addEventListener is from an element that is in home.handlebars only]

Now let's say I click a menu item that loads the *license.handlebars*. All the elements in index.js will return null if they were in *home.handlebars*. Any help?

My solution:

I probably could wrap my elements that are needed for each sub-document. In an *if* statement. So it would check it on each page load. But I looking for a more practical solution. Thank you.

App is using the MEVN stack.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question, but if you have a single JavaScript file that is included on all of your pages then any code in that script that interacts with DOM elements that are specific to only some pages would need to check for the existence of those elements before trying to attach listeners to them. This really has nothing to do with Handlebars.

Comment: @76484 Yup that's exactly my question. I wasn't sure if handlebars has a built in solution for this. Because I don't ever remember running into this problem when I first started working with html/plain js. But I was into Vue where all of this problem already taken cared off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could fix this by using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) at `node.addEventListener`.

Then if `dataFromDB` is `null` on that page, you won't get a runtime TypeError by attempting to access the `addEventListener` property on `null`.

```js
const dataFromDB = document.querySelector('.elementFromHome')
dataFromDB?.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click')
})
```

```html
<button class="elementFromHome">button from home</button>
```